# How to get a cake or pie like flavor with tea?

Tags: flavor, tea

My fiancée and I are becoming heavy tea drinkers. We wish to get our own flavored tea from raw leaves and other ingredients. I want to reproduce the flavor of an apple and cinnamon pie.

To do so, I will mix the tea leaves with dry apple and pieces of cinnamon stick. But I do not know what to use to reproduce the taste of the pastry. I am thinking about almond but I am not sure. This is what I am looking for : this pastry taste.

If anyone has already tried to get this (and succeeded !), I would like to know the trick !

Comment: Pastry usually tastes of its constituent fat (such as butter) more than anything. I'm not sure how you can incorporate that without actually dumping some in the cup. I suggest enjoying a shortbread biscuit with your cup of tea!

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I tasted some flavored tea bags which were reproducing muffin or cupcake like tastes. You are right but there might be an appropriate combination to get close to the thing. I think almond powder and shredded nuts may be a good shot. Unfortunately I do not have the hardware to check it at the moment.

Comment: I don't know that you'll extract much almond flavor by brewing the almonds with your tea. Maybe you could add a drop of butter flavoring and almond flavoring to your dry tea before steeping?

Answer (score 3):

From looking at several companies that sell cake and pie flavored teas, it appears that they use a couple of techniques that you may have uneven success with at home.

First off, you want to create a tea base that is as sweet as possible and creates a base flavor profile for you to use. Most companies achieve this by adding things like vanilla and rooibos to the tea. Vanilla is obvious, and rooibos has a smooth, slightly sweet, flavor reminiscent of pipe tobacco. Many also have dried fruit or spices added, as fitting for the flavor you're working toward.

Beyond this, some of the companies use natural and artificial flavorings. As the website for [David's Tea](http://www.davidstea.com) states, "The fact is, flavouring is the reason some of our favourite blends taste so great. We couldn't create the juicy melon flavour in Luscious Watermelon from dried melon alone."

You can add flavorings to your tea at home too, but they are very strong, so it may be hard to do it on a cup-by-cup basis. You may have better luck mixing the flavoring into a larger batch of tea. For things like cake and pie, I'd suggest adding butter flavor to mimic the pastry element, and an appropriate fruit flavor for pies. There are an amazing array of flavors available though, everything from "birthday cake" flavor to rosewater. Though they only sell to food service establishments, [Gold Coast Ingredients'](http://www.goldcoastinc.com/) website illustrates some of the crazy flavors available. The teacup is your oyster!

Comment: I just noticed that the website doesn't have the full listing, but Gold Coast's print catalog has 8 different cake flavors as well as a pie crust flavor and many other pastry flavors.